# Yshout5 in a Wordpress Widget?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, widget

I'm having an issue getting [Yshout5](http://yurivish.com/yshout/) working inside a Widget on my Sidebar, it doesn't show at all.

The instructions say to place the following code inside `<head>` (I  placed inside Header.php)

```
    <script src="yshout/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="yshout/js/yshout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="yshout/example/css/light.yshout.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
       new YShout();
       yPath: '/yshout',
    log: 1
 });

    </script>
```

And to place the following code wherever you want the Shoutbox to appear:

```
<div id="yshout"></div>
```

It just refuses to show up.

I have tried to contact the developer only to receive no response.

Can anyone help me out? Am I doing something wrong? 
I will gladly give the full plugin to anyone who needs it to figure out my problem.

**Any response is greatly appreciated, Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is broken:

```
   new YShout(); // creates a new YShout without any options
   yPath: '/yshout', // rest is broken code
log: 1
 });
```

Should be:

```
new YShout({ // pass the config object in
   yPath: '/yshout',
   log: 1
});
```